# Edit Subtotal of completed order

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, database-update

please help me edit the subtotal of a completed order, There was an order placed for COD and it was delivered with invoice photoshoped with new values however i want to change the subtotal in the system. 
I knew it is possible through database edit. some one please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Data for invoices can be found in the `sales_flat_invoice` table in the database. You can edit whichever field you like.
In your case with *subtotal* it's 4 fields

- subtotal_incl_tax
- base_subtotal_incl_tax
- subtotal
- base_subtotal

Also check the `sales_flat_invoice_grid` table if you want to make sure the change also reflects in your invoice grid

Comment: Hi sander, sorry for being dumb again, where do i find the sales_flat_invoice? coz i was looking for it in phymyadmin. i dont see anything with name of sales.

Comment: It's probably on page 2 or 3 of the tables

Comment: Hi Sander, That was just perfect on the second page, But i tried editing the shipping charge, i added like 30$ extra on an complete order both the  sales_flat_invoice and sales_flat_invoice_grid but still doesnt have effect o n the admin panel.

Comment: Are you looking at the invoice or order? Try editing the `sales_flat_order` too. Make a backup of the data first tho. You never know.

Comment: Hi sander, you the best, you have saved my day.. it worked perfectly fine and the dashboard values has also changed..

Comment: @nafizahmed you're welcome. don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Of course yes i will

Answer (score 1):

1. sales_flat_invoice
2. sales_flat_invoice_grid
3. sales_flat_order

These are the database rows where you can edit the values of invoice and order accordingly,

This table can be found in the database of your website, phpmyadmin on the second and third page respectively.